# Can't get firefox extension to work for all users

Tags: rhel, firefox

I am using a RHEL 64 bit system. I successfully have been able to install the Firefox extension, configure and use it with root.  However, it will not work when I log into as a standard user. I am using firefox 45.1.

I have put the information in `/usr/lib64/firefox/browser/extensions` but I cant seem to make it work.

This system isn't on a network which causes more challenges.

Answer (score 0):

First, you shouldn't use Firefox - or X Windows at all - as root as it's a security vulnerability. These applications are meant to be run with non-administrative privileges, in which case any bug or flaw in them would cause limited damage to your system.

To answer your question:

> If you're putting together an installer that needs to be able to install extensions for a toolkit-based application, such as Firefox or anything using XULRunner, Gecko 1.9 (Firefox 3) introduces an easy way to do this for Windows, OS X and Linux. Windows users have also had the ability to install extensions using the registry for some time. Now, on OS X and Linux, you can simply copy the extension into a predefined directory on the user's computer.
>
> To install extensions into these directories you must extract the extension to a directory with the same name as the the extension's ID. The ID is defined in the `install.rdf` of the extension, between the `<em:id></em:id>` tags. For WebExtensions based add-ons the ID is the value of the `applications.gecko.id` property within the `manifest.json` file.
>
> To install an extension to be used by all users on Linux, copy it to:
>
> ```
> /usr/lib/<vendor>/extensions/<appid>/
> ```
>
> Or...
>
> ```
> /usr/lib64/<vendor>/extensions/<appid>/
> ```
>
> Or...
>
> ```
> /usr/share/<vendor>/extensions/<appid>/
> ```
>
> To install an extension just for a specific user:
>
> ```
> ~/.<vendor>/extensions/<appid>/
> ```

(Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Installing_extensions)